# Content overlap for primefaces layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, primefaces, facelets

I'm using primefaces layout component and have a dropdown List in north layout unit. The dropdown will be cut and does not overlap through other layout units. How to change this?

Comment: Do you have any code? It will be easier for people to help you if they have something to go by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an easy solution via css:

```
.ui-layout-north {
    overflow:visible !important;
}

.ui-layout-north .ui-layout-unit-content {
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```